# What is my version of PyroCMS?

Tags: pyrocms

How can I find out what version of PyroCMS do I have installed on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your admin panel and look at the bottom as shown in screenshot --

[image]

**EDIT**

Check for the **README.md** file and look at the version --

```
# PyroCMS Community Edition

* [Website](http://pyrocms.com/)
* [Documentation](http://pyrocms.com/docs)
* [License](http://pyrocms.com/legal/license)
* [Forums](http://pyrocms.com/forums)
* Version: 2.0.1
```

Comment: Well it doesn't look like yours. Mine looks like this: [link](http://s14.postimage.org/ww0ntff81/stack.png)

Comment: @zwolin then check if you have any README.md in your directory and look at the version then and lemme know then

Comment: Ha, fantastic, that was it! * Version: 2.0.0-RC1 Thank you very much swapnesh

Answer (score 2):

look in system/{cms|pyrocms|whatever}/config/constants.php
there should be a version constant defined in there

Rares

Comment: There is. The constant's name is "CMS_VERSION".